# HZ value of a running kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, archlinux

I want to check HZ value of the Kernel running in my board.

Can you please guide me how to check. I want confirm what is configured in .config is same while running.

I could see following config parameters from .config

```
CONFIG_NO_HZ_COMMON=y
CONFIG_NO_HZ_IDLE=y
CONFIG_NO_HZ=y
CONFIG_HZ_FIXED=0
CONFIG_HZ_100=y
CONFIG_HZ=100
```

I am using TI's ARM based board and checked include/asm-generic/param.h file initially for HZ value then I checked .config file. I could see following lines in param.h. Please let me know If I the file "include/asm-generic/param.h" which I am checking is not correct.

```
#define HZ              CONFIG_HZ
#define USER_HZ         100
#define CLOCKS_PER_SEC  (USER_HZ)
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "HZ value"? Configuration value is the same as `.config` specifies because it was set during compilation. But actual system tick frequency depends on system load because you have some tickless options configured (`CONFIG_NO_HZ_*` options)

Comment: I want to check the execution time of few functions, so I thought I can check the jiffies while entering to the function and leaving from the function. If I want to represent time in secs then I have to devide with HZ value.                                                                                                        I tried with program @ http://www.advenage.com/topics/linux-timer-interrupt-frequency.php to know the HZ value. When I run the program but it is showing 4096 Hz, but in config file it is showing as 100(CONFIG_HZ=100). so my doubht here is HZ can change while kernel boots.

Comment: I doubt that program you refer reveal useful results -- POSIX timers may use hrtimers instead of system timer. Anyway, using `jiffies` to measure function execution time is strange: `jiffies` have 1ms..10ms resolution, while function execution time rarely crosses 1ms (unless it waits in `schedule()`). Maybe `ktime_get_ns()` is more useful in your case?

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find any documetation for ktime_get_ns, will it return Kernel time in nano secs(based on the name).
If i want function execution time then I have to call "ktime_get_ns" at the beginning and end of the function then the diff will give the function execution time in nano secs.

Comment: it seems ktime_get_ns function is not there in 3.12 kernel, which I am using. I think I can use ktime_to_ns in 3.12 kernel.

Comment: Yes, try to use it in conjuction with `ktime_get()`. There is also `sched_clock()`